# What is ag's (silver searcher) analogous option to grep's --line-buffered?

Tags: grep, ag

I'd like to use ag as if I would use grep with --line-buffered. Is it possible? If not what other options do I have to mimic such behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

I would like to have `ag` support `--line-buffered` style functionality as well.

I have raised [PR #719](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/issues/719) against the `ag` Github repo to request this functionality.

In the meantime, the best solution I've found is to wrap `ag` with `stdbuf -oL`.

```
# instead of grep
grep --line-buffered pattern

# use ag with a stdbuf wrapper
stdbuf -oL ag pattern
```

Comment: The rg (ripgrep) tool has now gained support for the --line-buffered switch as of v0.10.0.